# Why output of javascript code is not stable

Tags: javascript, json

I have written following code.

```
var arrCityrecordForADay = [];
function getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, callback) {

var toDaysTimestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - (24 * 60 * 60);
for (var i in cityArray) {

    for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=" + cityArray[i] + "&dt=" + toDaysTimestamp;

        $.ajax({
            url: jsonurl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            mimeType: "textPlain",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var arrCityRecordForDay = [];
                arrCityRecordForDay.push({
                    "cityName": data.list[0].city.name
                }, {
                    "weather": data.list[0].weather[0].description
                });

                var tempId = data.list[0].city.name+""+timeConverter(data.list[0].dt);
                arrCityrecordForADay.push({
                    tempId: arrCityRecordForDay // Here tempId is inserted as "tempId" not its value
                });

                if (((arrCityrecordForADay.length)) === cityArray.length) {
                    callback(arrCityrecordForADay);
                }

            }
        });
        toDaysTimestamp = toDaysTimestamp - (24 * 60 * 60);
    }
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var cityArray = new Array();
  cityArray[0] = "pune";
  cityArray[1] = "london";
  var result = document.getElementById("msg");
  getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, function (jsonData) {
  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      console.log(myJsonString);
  });
});

function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){

 var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp*1000);

 var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

 var year = a.getFullYear();

 var month = months[a.getMonth()];
 var date = a.getDate();
 var hour = a.getHours();
 var min = a.getMinutes();
 var sec = a.getSeconds();
 //var time = date+','+month+' '+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec ;
 var time = date+''+month+''+year;
 return time;
}
```

The output of program is not stable.I mean **after2-3 refresh some times it shows correct output  and some times wrong.**

correct output is

```
"[{"Pune25Dec2013":[{"cityName":"Pune"},{"weather":"Sky is Clear"}]},{"London22Dec2013":[{"cityName":"London"},{"weather":"overcast clouds"}]}]"
```

wrong output is

```
"[{"Pune25Dec2013":[{"cityName":"Pune"},{"weather":"Sky is Clear"}]},{"Pune24Dec2013":[{"cityName":"Pune"},{"weather":"Sky is Clear"}]}]"
```

**What is going wrong with workflow of code**.Thank you

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cz5tu/3/)

*Your response will be appriciated !!*

Comment: It depends upon your `cityArray`?  What are those and how are they passed?

Comment: What is the inner `for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {` loop for? I don't see `j` being used. Will be easier to debug w/ that removed

Comment: j is not used but toDaysTimestamp value is decremented in loop.j is just for iteration

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I had replied with an answer, I just updated it based on this new information. I understand what's going on.. it's because you are only showing the first 2 results (but actually making 4 requests - 2 for each city), and the order of the JSON requests returning with success callback is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to resolve your question:

1. In the success callback, if you create a hash variable it will allow you to set the tempId as the key of the object. (As it is now, your code sample does not even match the output you are showing).

   ```
   var arrCityRecordForDay = [];
   arrCityRecordForDay.push({
       "cityName": data.list[0].city.name
   }, {
       "weather": data.list[0].weather[0].description
   });

   var tempId = data.list[0].city.name+""+timeConverter(data.list[0].dt);
   // updated code
   var hash   = {};
   hash[tempId] = arrCityRecordForDay;

   arrCityrecordForADay.push(hash);
   ```
2. The callback is happening when arrCityrecordForADay length is same as cityArray, but because you are doing the inner loop with multiple timestamps for each city, that check should be different.

   ```
   // update length check (the 2 here should be however much inner loop is)
   if (((arrCityrecordForADay.length)) === cityArray.length * 2) {
       callback(arrCityrecordForADay);
   }
   ```
3. I confirmed the JSON response for "London" periodically returns first on a page refresh.  You are firing off multiple JSON requests and they can come back in any order. So, your `arrCityrecordForADay` array can have London first or Pune (and either date for either city), depending on speed of requests.  To make it deterministic, you could sort alphabetically. Or just store as an object (hash) instead of array.  This item will make more sense once you fix issue 2 above.

To sort, one way is to use an array of arrays, rather than an array of hashes.. (simpler model, since each hash is only one element anyway) and then define a sort method.

```
var tempId = data.list[0].city.name+""+timeConverter(data.list[0].dt);
// array instead of hash
arrCityrecordForADay.push([tempId, arrCityRecordForDay]);

if (((arrCityrecordForADay.length)) === cityArray.length * 2) {
  callback(arrCityrecordForADay.sort(compareCities));
}

...

// define this on page somewhere - looks at first element in array (the "tempId" value from above)
function compareCities(a,b) {
    if (a[0] < b[0])
        return -1;
    if (a[0] > b[0])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you know any technique to sort this json array.Because it not normal array.Its structure is different.

Comment: I updated answer with a suggestion. My suggestion involves changing the structure of the arrCityrecordForADay, but it becomes easier to work with, and has all the same information.

Comment: You are really master in JS.Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I am not aware of this sort technique.This sort is working for 2 loops.Will it work for more that two.

Comment: Yup, the sort will work for any number of cities and timestamps, as long as you keep "tempId" unique (which it is so far).